# Spring : How to configure tomcat Datasource Programatically in Groovy DAO

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, groovy

I have my tomcat datasource configured in XML as below:

```
<bean id="docDataSource"
    class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" 
    destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${doc.database.driver}" 
    p:url="${doc.database.url}"
    p:username="${doc.database.user}" 
    p:password="${doc.database.password}"
    p:validationQuery="select 1" 
    p:testOnBorrow="true" 
    p:minIdle="2" 
    p:maxIdle="4" 
    p:maxActive="6" 
    p:defaultTransactionIsolation="1">
</bean>
```

And my customDAO(groovy class) uses the above datasource as below

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import javax.sql.DataSource
import java.util.Map
import java.util.Map.Entry
import java.util.ResourceBundle

@Component
public class customDao implements GroovyInterceptable {

    @Autowired
    private Services services

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("docDataSource")
    private DataSource            dataSource
   // implementation    
}
```

I wanna switch my tomcat dataSource to a class file instead of XML. Can someone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the piece of code you can follow (with PostgreSQL, but it should more or less work the same):

```
import org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

import javax.sql.DataSource

@Configuration
class PostgreSQLDatasourceConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = 'dataSource')
  DataSource ds(@Value('${DATABASE_URL}') String databaseFullUrl) {
    assert databaseFullUrl, 'Database URL is required to start the application'

    URI uri = new URI(databaseFullUrl)
    def (_, dbUsername, dbPassword) = (uri.getUserInfo() =~ /(.*):(.*)/)[0]

    (DataSource) new PGPoolingDataSource().tap {
      url = "jdbc:postgresql://$uri.host:${uri.port}$uri.path"
      password = dbPassword
      user = dbUsername
    }
  }
}
```